# Kotlin compiler showing errors without line numbers

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am working on Android Studio. The "build" tab says there are six errors but all it prints are the following:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
error: Cannot find getter for field.
error: Cannot find setter for field.
error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
error: Cannot find getter for field.
error: Cannot find setter for field.
```

There is not much here that is useful to me because I have multiple Entities and DAOs. How do I get access to the actual line numbers causing trouble?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208909/typeconverters-cannot-figure-out-how-to-save-this-field-into-database

Comment: In that post, the compiler pointed the user to the problem. In my case all I got is what I am showing. Also I am not using any type converters at all.

Comment: @salyela You might tell us the type of DB you are using and also consider logcat it tells you line numbers under the tab marked ERRORS

Comment: Logcat is empty: nothing there. Also my DB extends `RoomDatabase()`. I am looking to see if I could get the build tab to point me to more data but no luck. I even tried `File > Settings > Kotlin Compiler` and added `--stacktrace --debug` there but still no luck.

Comment: Please try creating a [minimal verifiable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to narrow the problem down.

Comment: You can also try to compile from command line, to see if it is a problem with android studio or with the compiler.