# Polymorphism in Android Room when extending a non-Entity class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

My server is sending me a list of object type Parent, as `List<Parent> parents.` I need to save this list in Room and to do so I need a PrimaryKey. So what I try to do in room is create something like

```
@Entity
class Child(mApple:String,mOrange:String):Parent(mApple,mOrange){
    @PrimaryKeyy(autoGenerate=true)
    var id:Int=0
}
```

And here is what parent looks like:

```
//it's a java class and so to be complete I will recreate it in Java
class Parent{
    private final String mApple;
    private final String mOrange;
    private final String mDerivative;

    public Parent(String apple, String orange){
        mApple=apple;
        mOrange=orange;
    mDerivation = someMagic(apple,orange)
    }

    //then a bunch of methods for dealing with the state variables
}
```

The reason I want to extend Child from Parent is because it makes working with both Child and Parent together easy. But room is not compiling and I suspect it has to do with this. Unfortunately, Kotlin is not pointing me to where the error is occuring.

1. Is the error really due to the fact that Parent is not an Entity and that `derivative` does not provide a setter?
2. [How do I get Android Studio to show me more details about this bug, such as line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380655/kotlin-compiler-errors-without-line-numbers) (linked to related questions)

The only errors I am able to get from the `build` tab:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. 
error: Cannot find getter for field.    
error: Cannot find setter for field.    
error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.  
error: Cannot find getter for field.    
error: Cannot find setter for field.
```